# Google toolbar truncating site

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I've got a site I'm working on it's just a html site with Wordpress integrated to allow a few dynamic features for the client. For some reason IE with Google Toolbar enabled truncates the information and strips the css. In other words it's like it does read anything until it get half way down the page. When you refresh a few times it will change what it does and doesn't display. If I remove the wordpress code fragment at the top(see below) it works, but of course all the dynamic content goes away. The weird thing is that if it's WP generated page it works just fine.

```
<?php
require('./cms/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

I'm a little lost on this. I'm not doing anything I haven't done several times before with fine results and I can't find anything about it online. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Just for anybody else who experiences this I did find a fix. If you move the wordpress header in between the </head> and <body> tags it will fix this problem.